# How to disable OSMC from turning on TV automatically?

Tags: osmc

I installed OSMC on my Raspberry Pi as a home media center. However whenever I boot up my Raspberry Pi, it will turn my TV on automatically.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour through some configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using an HDMI connection, the power on signal is probably sent using [CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control), which is a feature of HDMI.

To disable CEC in OSMC, you'll need to SSH into your Pi, then open `/boot/config.txt`. Here's how to do it with the `nano` editor:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Then, add the following line (**or, if the `hdmi_ignore_cec` is present and set to 0, set it to 1**):

```
hdmi_ignore_cec=1
```

Note that you'll lose all power on ability from the Pi by doing this. Once you've set that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Reboot your Pi, and test if the issue is resolved. If not, it's likely to be a setting on your TV which switches it on when an input changes. Consult your TV documentation if that's the case.